# What is the cost / complexity of a String.indexOf() function call

Tags: java, string

What is the cost / complexity of a String.indexOf() function call?

Comment: In what language, and compared to what? What are the function's arguments - does it take a string, a char, a custom comparer?

Comment: Is it java that you are talking about?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity

Answer (score 15):

IIRC Java's implementation of `.indexOf()` is just the [naive string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), which is `O(n+m)` average and `O(n*m)` worst case.

In practice this is fast enough; I tested it for relatively large needle (>500 char) and haystack (few MB) strings and it would do the matching in under a second (in an average household computer). Mind you I forced it to go through the whole haystack.

Comment: I know it is long time ago but do you know where you got that from? I'd need that information for my bachelor thesis and I don't know if Stackoverflow would be an acceptable reference for a thesis ;)

Comment: @odaa I ran some experiments and wrote a paper on it when I was in college.

Comment: @NullUserException, Why do you say that `O(n+m)` is the average case? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752295/632951 seems to contradict that point.

Comment: @Pacerier O(n+m) average case, O(n*m) worst case.

Comment: @NullUserException it would be great, if you will show your benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

In java, if the call is string1.indexOf(string2) the time cost would be O(m - n) where m is the length of string1 and n is the length of string2.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the implementation.

For example, when searching for a string within a longer string, "The Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm takes an additional constant amount of space to complete a search within 2n comparisons (as opposed to 3n for Boyer-Moore), where n is the number of characters in the text to be searched." (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)).

Comment: @caleb: Really, how can you tell from the question?