# Algorithm for sub-string search in a large String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am just checking for an efficient algorithm with best computational complexity to check if a child string - `tobeVerified` exists in a huge parent string

I was going through different algorithms but I am yet to find something which offers O(n)

I came up with the below implementation using `HashSet` which is gives me `O(n+m) ~ O(n)`

I wanted to check if this is the right way of doing it or if any other optimization is possible. But in this approach there is problem of consuming more space

```
String parent = "the value is very high";
    String tobeVerified = "is";
    Set wordSet = new HashSet<String>();    
    String[] words = parent.trim().toUpperCase().split("\\s+");
    //This is O(n) n - Parent Size  m - substring size
    for(String word: words){
        wordSet.add(word);      
    }
    //This is O(1)
    System.out.println(wordSet.contains(tobeVerified.toUpperCase()));
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with String.contains()? My guess is that it's way more efficient than your algorithm.

Comment: @JBNizet .. `String.contains()` has a complexity of `O(m*n)`. It again calls `indexOf()` which has this complexity .. please check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity

Comment: Behind the scenes `contains()` again follows similar logic like `substring()` .. only difference being it returns a `boolean`

Comment: So what? What makes you think it's slower than trimming the whole string (already O(n) if a trim is needed)), converting to uppercase (O(n)), splitting with a regex (O(n) with a big number of memory allocation, copies of arrays, creation of many String objects), filling a hashset (O(n), creation of many entry objects, memory allocation, hashCode computation), lookup (O(1)), garbage collection. I mean just comparing each word you put in the set to the searched string, and not building the set at all would already be faster.

Comment: If you're going to scan the entire string with a regular expression anyway (`split()`), why not just use regex? E.g. `"(?i)\\btobeVerified\\b"`

Comment: Not to mention that indexOf() (called by contains()) is an "intrinsic" method. The JVM actually has a fast, native implementation of this method.

Comment: Do you use the same huge string many times with different patterns?

Comment: @JBNizet .. Yes , I agree with you that all the auxiliary steps like `trim()` and `split()` do add a lot of overhead and also ... instead of using the set I can do a comparison directly

Comment: @JBNizet .. as the answer pointed out .. Boyer-Moore algorith gives me a O(n+m) and looks promising and yupp . .better than `contains()`

Comment: @Andreas .. Yes, totally agree with you ... we can directly provide the regex  and the size of the split array should give info on the presence of the sub string .. Thanks ..  And yeah even split() especially with regex rather a simple charecter does take a lot of time and memory

Comment: @MBo ... yes , The huge string remains same with different patterns ..

Comment: @AdityaReddy What split array? You use that regex with [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) to locate the word. You don't use `split()` at all. That would be a total waste of time.

Comment: @AdityaReddy So you can try to build appropriate data structure once - suffix array, suffix tree or trie, and search patterns in it with high speed

Comment: @MBo .. sure .. Thats a good idea as a long term solution .. will give it a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the classic `O(n+m)` substring search algorithms is [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).  It should have better performance than `String.contains` or `String.indexOf` for sufficiently large strings.

There's a Java implementation of the algorithm on that wikipedia page link above, but it's written to use a `char[]` array as input instead of on an instance of the String class. So either modify the code to work with a String parameter , or take into account the additional cost, O(n), of cloning a `String` into a `char[]`.

One little issue I spotted on the wikipedia code. It assumes character values are only in the 8-bit range.  You might need to modify this line:

```
final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 256;
```

To be this:

```
final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 65536;
```

**Update**: I updated the wikipedia page code appropriately to have the correct value for `ALPHABET_SIZE`. Confirmed the original bug existed and wrote a unit test to validate the fix.

Comment: Thanks .. this looks promising .. will run some tests with this

Comment: I fixed the code on the wikipedia page with the change described above.  I wrote a unit test to confirm different string patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a Boyer-Moore implementation, as suggested in [answer by selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41647967/5221149), if profiling shows that you truly have a performance issue.

Until then, just do a simple regex search:

```
String textToSearch = "the value is very high";
String wordToFind = "is";
String regex = "(?i)\\b" + Pattern.quote(wordToFind) + "\\b";
boolean found = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(textToSearch).find();
```

`(?i)` makes the search case-insensitive, and `\\b` matches word-boundary, e.g. ensuring that `is` will not match `this`. Since you're doing word-search, `Pattern.quote()` is likely unnecessary, but better be safe than sorry.

Comment: what about if we want to also get the count of matches?