# How do I calculate the runtime complexity of this implementation of longest common prefix algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} strs
 * @return {string}
 */
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    if(strs.length ===0) return '';
    let prefix = strs[0];
    for(let i=0; i< strs.length; i++) {
        while(strs[i].indexOf(prefix) !=0) {
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length -1);
            if(!prefix) return '';
        } 
    }

    return prefix;
};
```

Here for loop runs O(n) times and while loop within checks whether prefix matches the elements in for loop iteration - is the while loop O(n) times too? Please provide insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let *n* be the number of strings in `strs`, and let the average (or longest) string length be *m*. Your algorithm with line numbers is as follows.

```
1. var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
2.    if(strs.length ===0) return '';
3.    let prefix = strs[0];
4.    for(let i=0; i< strs.length; i++) {
5.        while(strs[i].indexOf(prefix) !=0) {
6.            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length - 1);
7.            if(!prefix) return '';
8.        } 
9.     }
10.    return prefix;
11. };
```

We only need estimate the number of times the for loop (line 4) and the while loop (line 5) are executed. As you noted that the for loop is executed *n* times, since *n* = `strs.length`. However, you do have a return statement within the while loop, so execution *might* never reach line 10.

Now, for the while loop. As described, this loop is executed the size of the prefix (*m*) and in each iteration the indexOf operation takes *O(m^2)* in the worst case (see next paragraph). Thus, the time complexity of your algorithm as a function of the number of strings (*n*) is *O(nm^2)*.

We could also look at the time complexity as a function of *m*, the number of characters in each string. How long does it take to compare two strings? Java's implementation in this case will take *O(mk)*, where *m* and *k* are the lengths of the two strings respectively (see this answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity)) and the [String class code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) for details.

Comment: thanks a lot  @rrufai but I got another doubt after reading one of the comments in the link shared above. Per Andreas, O(m^2) is worst case and least likely, cos pattern matching will stop as soon as first mismatch occurs and amortized, it is O(1.1 * n), which is O(n). So do we calculate the average case or the worst one?

Comment: @novembersky: Usually, for big O analysis, we go with the worst-case. In fact, it's sometimes called worst-case analysis. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ! Can you explain me " As described, this loop is executed the size of the prefix (m)" ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I understand that indexOf at least in Java is O(n*m). So for each For iteration,how many times IndexOf is executed?
Should the time complexity be like :
O (n * (Time while loop executes * (n*m)) ?