# Algorithmic complexity of string rotation

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm a little new to complexity, and was trying to determine the algorithmic complexity of the process below, which calculates whether a given string is a rotation of another given string (i.e., if "bcdea" is a rotation of "abcde"). I'm pretty sure this breaks down to O(n), as each check in the function breaks down to n at worst (I think!). Does that sound about right?

```
public class Rotate {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str1 = "abcde";
            String str2 = "bcdea";
            System.out.println(isRotation(str1, str2));
        }
        
        public static boolean isRotation(String str1, String str2) {
          if(str1 == null || str2 == null){
            return false;
          }
          
          System.out.println(str1 + str2);
          if(str1.length() == str2.length() && (str1 + str2).indexOf(str2) > 0){
            return true;
          }
          
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Algorithmic complexty does not measure runtime.

Comment: Gah, sorry, I meant algorithmic complexity, not runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The expression at issue is this one:

```
(str1 + str2).indexOf(str2)
```

Everything else in your method is obviously `O(1)`, so whatever the complexity of this expression is is going to be the complexity of the method as a whole. Let's say that `n1` represents the length of the `str1` and `n2` represents the length of `str2`, for our purposes.

Now, there are two parts here. String concatenation can generally be assumed to have `O(n1 + n2) == O(n)` runtime, as the component operations are (1) allocating space (constant), copying `str1` (takes `n1` time), and copying `str2` (takes `n2` time).

Meanwhile, [Java's `String.indexOf()` has complexity `O(m * n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity), where `m` is the length of the search string and `n` is the length of the pattern string. Here, that resolves to `O((n1 + n2) * n) == O(n * n) == O(n^2)`.

So the complexity of the method as a whole would be closer to `O(n^2)` than to `O(n)`. The complexity could be easily lowered by using a more efficient, lower-complexity implementation of `indexOf()`, as mentioned in the linked question.

If we look at algorithmic complexity, then the method is `O(n)`, since `indexOf()` is the limiting element and there exist `O(n)` implementations of that. However, if we look at runtime complexity, taking this as an implementation rather than an algorithm, then the runtime would be `O(n^2)`.

---

(sidenote: I think it should be `(str1 + str1).indexOf(str2)`, not `(str1 + str2).indexOf(str2)`. But that doesn't significantly change the complexity, and isn't the point of this answer)

Comment: Fantastic insight, thank you very much. As was noted above, I misspoke and actually was just looking for the algorithmic complexity of the program, which it sounds like I was on the right path in my assumption. In a similar vein, would your answer hold true for the space complexity as well?

Comment: Or, I should say, the algorithmic complexity is O(n^2) due to the concatentation in addition to the usage of indexOf()? In which case, delegating the concatenation to a separate action would reduce the entire function to O(n)? Assuming O(n) would be the space complexity as well?

Comment: @ZapRowsdower Don't forget, `O`-notation is a measure of complexity _class_ - an algorithm with `2n` operations has the same class as one that takes `20n` operations (any fixed, constant number of `n`s - the runtime grows linearly as `n` increases). Accordingly, if you have multiple operations with the same complexity in sequence, they add together but the function remains in the same complexity class. In this case space complexity would be `O(n)` also - the only real space you're allocating is the space for the concatenation, which is exactly twice the size of the input.