# Time complexity of a nested while loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, data-structures, time-complexity

For the "longest common prefix" problem on Leetcode, Leetcode said that this solution is O(S) complexity where S is the sum of all characters. https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/solution/

Solution:

```
 public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return "";
    String prefix = strs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++)
        while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            if (prefix.isEmpty()) return "";
        }        
    return prefix;
}
```

Isn't a while loop inside of a for loop n^2 though? I thought all nested loops were n^2.

Comment: If there is a condition inside any of the loops, that breaks the loop the complexity changes

Comment: And even if it doesn't, the complexity is not necessarily `O(N^2)`.  It depends on how the inner loop's number of iterations relates to the `N` parameter.  It could be `O(N^2)` or `O(NM)` or even `O(N)` depending on the *algorithm*.

Comment: Short cuts like "all nested loops are `O(N^2)`" are dangerous.  If you need to, you should work out the complexity from first principles ... like you were (or should have been!) taught in your DS&A course.

Comment: Should've added a disclaimer - I'm completely self taught :) studied DS&A on my own well enough to get FAANG job the first time around though

Answer (score 2):

For O(n) time complexity we must define n. It is typically the length of the input array. However in this case, we instead define S to be the sum of all characters as the length of the input array cannot accurately describe our time complexity.

The complexity of O(n^2) will be if we are iterating over the same array of length n with both the for loop and while loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't a while loop inside of a for loop n^2 though?

Not generally, but in this case you are right: the algorithm has a worst time complexity of O(²). The article is wrong.

Let's take as input the following two strings (respectively 10 and 20 characters long):

```
abbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaacccccccccc
```

The outer loop will only make one iteration.

The inner loop will make 10 iterations, each time performing `indexOf` and then making the `prefix` string one character shorter, from its initial size of 10 until it is just "a".

Java's `indexOf` method [has in general a O() time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity). The first time it executes, it will try to match the `prefix` string in the second string at index 0, 1, ..., 8, 9, each time failing at the second character comparison (of "b" with another letter). So we have 20 character-to-character comparisons here. The second time it executes, `prefix` has one less "b", and so there are now 18 comparisons, then 16, then 14, ... 4, and then the last iteration (when `prefix` is just one character): 1 (success!), making a total of 109 character-to-character comparisons!

Clearly this leads to a quadratic complexity.

The problem is with the `indexOf` method. The code should use the [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method instead, as it makes no sense to look at other indices than index 0. Then the algorithm will have a O() complexity. This is easy to see: every character in the strings S<sub>2</sub> ... S<sub>n</sub> is compared *at most once* with a character from S<sub>1</sub>.

So the code should have:

```java
while (!strs[i].startsWith(prefix)) {
```

> I thought all nested loops were n^2.

No, that is not generally true. As  here is the total number of characters, we can see that nor the outer loop, nor the inner loop has a number of iterations that corresponds to *that* .

Here are some other examples of nested loops that do not represent a complexity of O(²)

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j*=2)
        //...
```

This is O(log)

Or:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j % 3 == i % 3) break;
        //...
    }
```

This is O()